# Why isn't jquery loading images from a folder in Wordpress posts?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I got this jQuery code from stack overflow for loading images from a folder.This code load images if use in html page in Localhost but if I use it in Wordpress post no images are being displayed.

```
var folder = "image/pic/";

$.ajax({
url : folder,
success: function (data) {
    $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
        if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
            $("body").append( "<img  src='"+ folder + val +"'>" );
        } 
    });
}
});
```

I have also tried using php code for loading images from a folder using the Insert PHP plugin to insert the PHP code,but then only 'echo' command seems to work but the code to display the images does not work in Wordpress post.The PHP code is given below.

```
[insert_php] 
$dirname = "image/pic/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.png");

foreach($images as $image) {
echo '<div class="imageWrapper"> 
  <img src="'.$image.'" ><br/> <br/>
     </div>' ;
 }
[/insert_php]
```

I will be happy if anyone could provide me with the solution.I have multiple posts and I want to load images from unique folder in each post.Any suggestion besides using Jquery and PHP code is also welcomed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you uploaded the images? to the right directory? with the right file permission?

Comment: Yes! as I said the code are working fine in html page in Localhost.

Comment: oh you mean wordpress is running on localhost?